# Distributing private win app in UWP

Tags: uwp

**SCENARIO**

I'm new in UWP tech and i would like to create and distribute my first UWP app.

It's a company app so it won't be sold and it won't be public on the store. Then i will edit the app and i will deploy it again.

I can't find docs about it.

**QUESTIONS**

Is there a particular process to do it (or it consists only of a copy of files - i read about powershell)? I already read [Is the Windows App Store required for a UWP application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163359/is-the-windows-app-store-required-for-a-uwp-application) so you can avoid LOB solution. Moreover that post starts from a known solution.

Is it easy for the final user the process of updating it? Easy=opinion so: can you describe it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163359/is-the-windows-app-store-required-for-a-uwp-application

Comment: Thanks but it's not complete and it starts from a known solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the Windows App Store required for a UWP application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163359/is-the-windows-app-store-required-for-a-uwp-application)

Comment: I edited my post. Please don't suggest any post is about topic but it's  completely different for level. I got also a downvote!. Don't search on Google + Stack Overflow :) I prefer answers belong who has already a solution. The post you have linked starts from side loading. What is side loading? Maybe side loading can be an answer to my post? Is side loading explained in that post? No answers about copy of files and how users can update...

Comment: This article has basic information about sideloading if that's what you are looking for: https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-appx-files-windows-10/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For enerprises there is Microsoft Store for Business which makes an app available only to associated accounts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/distribute-lob-apps-to-enterprises
2. You can publish an app to regular Store but hide it and make available only using promotion code.
3. There is always posibility to sideload your app, which means running powershell that installs your app. In visual studio you can distribute your app trough Hockey App, which is portal where you upload your app and invited users will be notified about new version. However, they will need to download it, unpack and run the powershell.

Answer (score 2):

You can submit the app to the Store and make it available only to people with a link. The app would not be visible in the Store.

Answering your other question: as far as I know, you pay only once for a lifetime developer licence, you do not pay for submitting apps.

Comment: And to avoid to enable developer mode? final users can't do it.

Comment: You don't need developer mode if downloading the app from the store via link, since it has a proper certificate.

Comment: Even for SideLoading, you don't need Developer Mode. You just need to enable SideLoading and your app has to be signed using trusted certificate. I think sideloading can be enabled using Group Policies.